# Pivot dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot

I am trying to pivot a dataframe in Python for a school project. 
I know how to transform the rows into column, but what I don't know is how to populate that new columns with the value 1 or 0 depending the case. For example, now I have something like this:

```
Code   Product
1       Water
1       Coke
2       Wine
3       Apples
```

and I want to turn it into something like this:

```
Code   Water  Coke  Wine  Apples
1       1       1    0      0      
2       0       0    1      0
3       0       0    0      1
```

I searched the web and I could't find anything. Also, I'm not that advanced in Python language.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(index=df.Code, columns=df.Product)

Product   Apples  Coke  Water  Wine
Code                              
1             0     1      1     0
2             0     0      0     1
3             1     0      0     0
```

Comment: How would you do the opposite! Turn a df that looked like the crosstab into a 1 row/column df?

Comment: Check `pd.melt` @HiFizzle_